# Detecting interface name on CISCO ASA configuration

Tags: command-line-interface, cisco-asa, snmp

I use the following command to configure the Cisco ASA to allow me query snmp

```
snmp-server host inside 10.20.30.40 community public version 2c
```

I need to automate this task and my question is how to detect the interface name (`inside` in this case) knowing only the IP address using SSH?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear for me (how do you plan to automate your task ?), for now I can only give hints about what you can do.

If you've got a linux machine, ssh to your ASA and save the `show ip address` command output locally :

```
ssh user@ssh-server.com '( show ip address )' > /tmp/ip_address
```

now you have a file on your linux machine called `ip_address` that contains something like this :

```
System IP Addresses:
Interface                Name                   IP address      Subnet mask
Method 

GigabitEthernet0         DMZ                    10.10.10.1      255.255.255.0
CONFIG

GigabitEthernet1         INSIDE                 10.10.20.1      255.255.255.0   
CONFIG

Current IP Addresses:
Interface                Name                   IP address      Subnet mask     
Method 

GigabitEthernet0         DMZ                    10.10.10.1      255.255.255.0   
CONFIG

GigabitEthernet1         INSIDE                 10.10.20.1      255.255.255.0      
CONFIG
```

then use `awk` or `sed` to get the interface name corresponding to an ip address.

Comment: @Adassko if you could give more details about your question it would be great.

Comment: I only need SSH commands which will allow me to get this information. `show ip address` shows me this:

 `    Group : 1`
 `    Management System IP Address:`
 `            ip address 10.20.30.40 255.255.255.0`
 `    Management Current IP Address:`
 `            ip address 10.20.30.40 255.255.255.0`

It doesn't give me any information about the interface I should use to reach my IP. It's important that it's ASA device

Comment: check if `nameif` is configured on ASA use `show running-config`, the `nameif` command gives the interface a name and assigns a security level,  typical names are outside, inside, or DMZ.
It would be helpful if you posted you're ASA firewall configuration.